# Can't use keyboard in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keyboard

I'm using a raspberry pi 3A+ and have been trying to use the keyboard for hours.  I have written this code:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("You pressed 'a'.")
        break
```

Every time I run it the console just says this long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yesnt/Documents/programming/NICK.py", line 3, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 410, in is_pressed
    _listener.start_if_necessary()
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 196, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 109, in build_device
    ensure_root()
  File "/home/yesnt/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 174, in ensure_root
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
```

I have only started playing with the raspberry today, so I still don't know a lot of things. Can anyone help me fix this? Also I'm trying to use it for a circuit to turn on and off a LED, but I think it won't have any interference on that. Thanks

I've installed the keyboard in every single way shape and form, but nothing. install keyboard, pip install keyboard, pip3 install keyboard, sudo pip3 install keyboard,....

Comment: could you use input command instead of the keyboard library?

Comment: since you are learning you may be interested in the utility 'evtest'.  install with sudo apt install evtest.  when you run it, you can select which input device you want to watch; do this and then press keys and watch the output.  one can write python code to read the output of evtest and then not use the keyboard library

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permission to access raw devices in `/dev/input/input*`, that is documented in the package you use: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

You could run your program as root (sudo myProgram.py) or check the permission of the input devices this script want to access. I checked my linux machine and the devices are owned by `root` and group `input`, so it could be a solution to add the group `input` to your user. But you have to check the permission on YOUR raspberry pi.

Comment: I tried "sudo python NICK.py" and I think it worked because it didn't show any error but when I pressed "a" it still wouldn't print it. Maybe it prints on another place idk

Comment: when you run python as sudo you are likely getting a different environment and so your PATH and PYTHONPATH variables will be different.  You could even be getting python2 instead of python3.  so, this solution will be problematic and require some more testing. you can use import os; os.environ['PATH'] to check this

Answer (score 0):

simply run your code on terminal with sudo
like ---- sudo python3 filename.py